# How can I discover the issuer of an opaque access token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'm using OpenID Connect to control access to my REST API. One of the things I need to do when servicing a request is get the [OIDC UserInfo](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo) based on the access token in request's `Authorization: Bearer ...` header.

To this point I've been working with JWTs and this works fine. I'm looking at expanding this to work with opaque tokens as well.

My strategy has been based on my understanding of the [OpenID Connect Discovery spec, section 4](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#ProviderConfig):

1. Extract the `iss` from the access token.
2. Discover the userinfo endpoint by getting `${iss}/.well-known/openid-configuration` and querying the JSON for `userinfo_endpoint`.
3. HTTP GET the `userinfo_endpoint`, passing the access token as an `Authorization: Bearer ...` header.

This works fine for opaque tokens... except for step 1. Currently, I have to know who the issuer is via an out-of-band mechanism because I don't know how to get the issuer from the opaque token (which, to be honest, makes sense given that it's *opaque*). I see a few possibilities:

- Maybe I'm just supposed to know who issued it and my question is misguided.
- Maybe the best thing to do is try a list of known issuers and see if one of them works.
- Maybe there's a mechanism for discovering the issuer of the opaque token. ([The spec refers to WebFinger](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#IssuerDiscovery), but that doesn't seem like it fits my use case.)
- Maybe there's something I haven't considered...

Thanks all for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

**You cannot discover *anything* from an opaque token *alone*.**

An opaque token could be anything, even just a UUID that serves as a key to a database table in the Authorization Server. The **only** way anything can be obtained with such a token is by calling the introspection endpoint.

(Even if there *is* anything encoded in the opaque token, the only way it *should* be decoded is by calling the introspection endpoint.)

To that extent, my original question was somewhat misguided in that I was attempting to decode something that doesn't intrinsically express its encoding. It's rather like trying to use a pointer without knowing what it points to. Indeed, I've found a number of places where the term "reference token" is used to mean "opaque token."

Thanks to [Gary Archer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67727138/42685) for some helpful feedback.

Comment: Hi, what out-of-band system did you use to pass the issuer ? I'm thinking of adding an extra http header AUTHORIZATION_ISSUER but I would love to know if there's a standard practice for that.
Note: I also thought of using the Authorization header directly (something like "Authorization: Bearer OPAQUETOKEN@https://idp.com/issuer" or "Authorization: Bearer OPAQUETOKEN https://idp.com/issuer") but I think it's too dangerous to change a standard header without the standard's approval. Do you know if I can ask about adding things to the standard somewhere ?

Comment: @jonenst If I understand your question, then 1) the OIDC call is passed **to** the issuer, so there's no need to add a header saying who the issuer is, and 2) using the `Authorization: Bearer <token>` technique (with nothing appended to the token) is what you want to do. There's no point passing the opaque token to anyone but the issuer, because it's basically a lookup key in the issuer's database. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But from what I understand, it's valid to pass the opaque Access token (it's the same for a jwt Access token) to a resource server (our API). Authorization servers provide the standard "introspection endpoint" to allow resource servers to validate opaque Access tokens (equivalent to verifying the cryptographic signature of jwt Access tokens)

Comment: That's correct. When the access token is opaque, the resource server just has to know who the issuer is rather than discovering it from the token itself. Even when using JWT access tokens, you have to (or maybe it's just _you should_; I don't remember) configure which issuers you will accept tokens from.... but I think I understand your original question better now: if you wanted to pass a header or something in the URL that indicated which issuer provided the token, I guess you could... but that seems fraught. Better to just configure one allowed issuer (or a couple to try in sequence).

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your comment. Yes indeed I started with a list of accepted issuers, they all send JWT access tokens so I could easily validate the issuer and the cryptographic signature of the token. Then I added one more issuer, and this one sends opaque tokens. Moreover, the access token type (jwt or opaque) is a dynamic issuer configuration, so it might change anytime, so I would like to handle both types transparently in my API.

Comment: OK, seems like the only real thing you can do is try to inspect the token _as if_ it's a JWT and proceed according to how that goes: use the JWT issuer on success and fall back on your known opaque issuers. The only thing that gives me concern is if you have multiple possible opaque token issuers and you just blindly try sending a token to a whole bunch of different issuers until one succeeds. Unfortunately, I don't know of a "standard" way of figuring out which issuer supplied the opaque token, so your idea of including the issuer in (for example) a request header seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The standard mechanism for dealing with opaque tokens is via [introspection](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7662). Also the preferred option is for there to only be a single type of access token - issued by your Authorization Server (AS), which sits alongside your APIs.

The introspection result can be a claims payload or a JWT. It is common to plug in an API gateway, as in [this article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/integration-kong-open-source/), so that the gateway makes the actual introspection call. The gateway should then cache results for subsequent calls made with the same access token.

An opaque token is typically a GUID or something similar, and the issuer value is not stored in the token - it is instead stored in the issuing Authorization Server's back end state. The only way to determine the issuer is to try to introspect the token.

**FOREIGN ACCESS TOKENS**

Aim to avoid using foreign access tokens in your APIs as in the following examples. This can make it difficult to control data added to tokens and token lifetimes:

- User signs in with Google - then API uses Google access tokens
- User signs in with Microsoft - then API uses Microsoft access tokens

It is preferred instead to use 'federated login capabilities' of your Authorization Server, leading to the following cleaner result, and fewer issues:

- User signs in with Google - then API uses your AS access tokens
- User signs in with Microsoft - then API uses your AS access tokens

Comment: Thank you! A couple of follow-up questions:

* If you don't know who the issuer is, there's no way to do introspection. Correct?

* By "Authorization Server," you mean something like Okta/Auth0/Curity?

Comment: If you don't know who the issuer is you could attempt introspection against the wrong provider - which would be suboptimal. Yes - those providers could be used - or you could use a cloud one such as AWS Cognito or Azure AD. The key point is that the AS / instance is controlled by you so that your APIs get the token data they need.

Comment: I also want to use foreign tokens from multiple issuers. For very dynamic issuers, you can't even try a list of issuer (for example if you allow all subdomains of a domain, or based on wildcard patterns) because you can't generate all possible issuers from a pattern. I don't want to have my own autorization server to avoid maintenance costs when I can directly use the upstream authorization servers. Should there be a standard way to pass the issuer of an opaque token ? Inside the Authorization: Bearer TOKEN with a known syntax, or in a separate Authorization_issuer header ?

Comment: Opaque tokens are passed in the bearer header - eg this is how a mobile client would send them - and the mobile app would not know or care who the issuer was. The wider point is that third party access tokens (whether opaque or not) are not designed to use for authorization in your own APIs. Aim to use your own token service to validate external tokens (at least the ID token) and then issue its own token set. An authorization server does this for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and your time. The mobile app does know who the issuer is since it fetches the access token from the issuer before doing the request.

Do you have a reference to confirm the assertion that "third party access tokens (whether opaque or not) are not designed to use for authorization in your own APIs." ?

Comment: Not as such, though it should be fairly self evident whether this is the case. See if you can add custom scopes and claims for all of the providers you are using. Eg try adding a fixed `shipping:write` scope and a `subscription_level=gold` claim (calculated at runtime) to access tokens. If you can read these values in your APIs then all is well.